# Jenkins Pathignore Plugin installation failing

Tags: installation, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins installed on a Windows Server.

I am trying to add the plugin `Pathignore Plugin` which has a dependency on `Ruby-runtime`.

When I tried to add `Ruby-runtime` plugin, I've got the following error:

> Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\ruby-runtime\WEB-INF\lib\classes.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 10):

It appears to be caused by a long file name bug, I had to relocate our Jenkins install to the root of the drive, it then "just works"

- Stop the Jenkins Service
- Move the Jenkins folder to the drive root (i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins` to `C:\Jenkins`
- Edit the location of the service in the system registry
  [image: Registry location]
- Restart Jenkins

see [bug report here for more information](https://github.com/elvanja/jenkins-gitlab-hook-plugin/issues/19)

Comment: Is there a Mac Server solution?  My install is already in the root.  I appear to have some permissions when installing gems from the terminal CLI.  This lead me to install rbenv plugin in Jenkins and now I am stuck with two half-installed plugins (rbenv and rbenv-runtime)